# How to use calculated metrics in report created by mobile analytics apps?

Tags: google-analytics

Calculated metrics are not listed while creating a report in ios or mobile app. Is there any way to use them on mobile?

Comment: Do you mean updating the calculated metrics through an app you've written or viewing the calculated metrics within Google Analytics?

Comment: I want to use calculated metrics i wrote before when I use mobile app to create a report.